# flask not able to get the real ip of the remote client

Tags: python, flask

I am simply running a flask app and  not using nginx and uwsgi, yes my host is behind the load blancer .

I am trying to read all the keys which can read the IP address, but I am not getting the actual IP of the client.

X-Real-IP is changing on every request and X-Forwarded-For has only one IP address which is the loadbalancer IP.

Same issue with bottle. When I started the application directly python app.py , I am not able to get the real IP address.
Is this must to use uwsgi and nginx for a sample app to read IP?

If I use below configuration and forward the uwsgi_param I can read the list of IP address in the response.

Below wsgi_file.ini

```
[uwsgi] 
socket = 127.0.0.1:8000
plugin    = python
wsgi-file = app/app.py
process   = 3
callable = app
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen 3000;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


        location / {
                uwsgi_pass  0.0.0.0:8000; #unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
                include        /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        }
}
```

I started the nginx server and ran the application using command:
uwsgi --ini wsgi_file.ini.

Comment: You told us what you are **not** using, but what are you using? Don't say it's the **development** server.

Comment: Klaus , it's a very basic app and I am trying to see if I am able to catch the IP. I do not know If I answer your question

Comment: When I added nginx and uwsgi config to call this app. I got the correct IP Address.location / {
                uwsgi_pass  0.0.0.0:8000; #unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
                include        /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        }

Comment: How do you start your flask app? What load balancer are you using? Are there any other intermediaries between the client and the server besides this load balancer?

Comment: @Miguel edited my question , no not using other intermediaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IP address of the client can be obtained in Flask with `request.remote_addr`.

Note that if you are using a reverse proxy, load balancer or any other intermediary between the client and the server, then this is going to return the IP address of the last intermediary, the one that sends requests directly into the Flask server. If the intermediaries include the `X-Real-IP`, `X-Forwarded-For` or `Forwarded` headers, then you can still figure out the IP address of the client.

Comment: So for beginners, what check can done to recognize this is not real IP of client and IP exist in header is for proxy or load balancer, I know that user or server can update headers of request and request data, when to say I m not able to get the real IP block that request, it not related to question details.

Comment: There is no way to know if an IP address is an intermediary or a real client, because from the side of the server there is no difference. Most intermediaries add the headers mentioned above in my answer, so you can look for those in the request headers.